# Sql Compare Comma Separated Value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm searching a way to compare a value in the same cell.

For now I have a data that i get with a query and the output is like:

```
ID|firstname|lastName|Gender|Tag
1 |Jo       |Sav     |b     |sport,computer,sport
2 |Franck   |Gag     |b     |climbing, swimming
3 |Oli      |Dann    |b     |cycling,running,cycling
4 |Alyss    |Baby    |g     |make up, cycling
```

All I want is to get only the person who get duplicates data in tag columns.

So the output will be like:

```
ID|firstname|lastName|Gender|Tag
1 |Jo       |Sav     |b     |sport,computer,sport
3 |Oli      |Dann    |b     |cycling,running,cycling
```

Thanks in advance!

Edit #1:For people want to know how my schema is.

```
ID|firstname|lastName|Gender|Tag
1 |Jo       |Sav     |b     |sport
2 |Franck   |Gag     |b     |climbing
3 |Oli      |Dann    |b     |cycling
4 |Alyss    |Baby    |g     |make up
1 |Jo       |Sav     |b     |computer
1 |Jo       |Sav     |b     |sport
2 |Franck   |Gag     |b     |swimming
3 |Oli      |Dann    |b     |cycling
3 |Oli      |Dann    |b     |running
...
```

Comment: why are you storing data seprated by a comma in the first place?

Comment: Cause it's already a output that i get. It is what my client wants to have.

Comment: Stop storing data this way. Seriously, fix your design so you can write proper, relational queries without having to constantly look for tedious and inefficient workarounds.

Comment: fix your database design instead of working around this design flaw

Comment: Well guys i can have the data not in comma seperated value but i need to have the output as i shown

Comment: the data you have shown above is the output of your query or data that have been saved as csv? - just clarifying.

Comment: I have edit my post to show my original data before I put them in comma seperated value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this. The extra `EXISTS` clause checks if the `ID` is present in the records which has duplicate `Tag`.

```
SELECT  ID, firstname, lastName, Gender,
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + Tag
              FROM TableName
              WHERE ID = a.ID
              FOR XML PATH ('')) , 1, 1, '')  AS TagList
FROM    TableName AS a
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
            SELECT 1
            FROM tableName b
            WHERE b.ID = a.ID
            GROUP BY b.id, b.tag
            HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
        )
GROUP   BY ID, firstname, lastName, Gender
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9b032/4)